# How to repeat sounds using Tmediaplayer

Tags: delphi, audio, media-player, repeat

i am using delphi7. I want put a song in my program, but i don't want it to end never. I tried using a timer, but it didn't play the music:

```
procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
timer1.enabled:=true;
end;


procedure TForm1.Timer1Timer(Sender: TObject);
var playsound,destination:string;
begin

destination:=paramstr(0); 
playsound:=extractfilepath(destination)+'Soundtrack\play.wma';

mediaplayer1.FileName:=playsound;                
mediaplayer1.Open;
mediaplayer1.Play;                        //USING TMEDIAPLAYER

end;
```

There are no syntax errors in this code, however the song is not running, perhaps the timer is not for that job. How should i do it? Thanks

Comment: Now you will reload and restart the file once a second. So you will repeat the intro over and over again. Also, you really don't need two variables. I'd use zero. [Anyhow, reduction by one is trivial. And why do you call the path to the current EXE `destination`? It's like using the word 'telephone' to denote a 'cat'.]

Comment: Ok, but how do i make it automatically repeat the song? note that i don't press the play button, but it starts by itself

Comment: Although using a `TMediaPlayer` and a `TTimer` certainly isn't optimal for this, this is how you should have done it: First, when your application initialises, load the file in the media player. Hence, this should be done *only once*, not once a second! Second [no pun intended], you set the interval of the timer to the duration of the media file (plus perhaps some pause). Third, you start your timer. The `OnTimer` event should simply restart the song. That would have been a valid logic, but as I have already pointed out, you shouldn't use this approach at all.

Comment: Also, you claim that you get no sound at all. That might be because the intro of the song is longer than 1 second. Or there could be some other issue (e.g. incorrect handling of the `TMediaPlayer` control). Are you sure you can start the song *once* using the `TMediaPlayer` control? If not, then you need to figure out how to do that *before* you get on to the next step: making it reapeat indefintely.

Comment: won't it work if i just use the notify event of the mediaplayer?

Comment: Perhaps. I don't know the `TMediaPlayer` by heart (have never used it). Consult the documentation. But do you really want its GUI?

Comment: Ok, Andreas, you are right, i will use playsound insteed

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't use a timer for this.  Use the `TMediaPlayer.OnNotify` event instead:

```
procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  mediaplayer1.FileName := extractfilepath(paramstr(0))+'Soundtrack\play.wma';
  mediaplayer1.Notify := true;
  mediaplayer1.Wait := false;          
  mediaplayer1.Open;
end;

procedure TForm1.MediaPlayer1Notify(Sender: TObject);
begin
  case mediaplayer1.Mode of
    mpOpen, mpStopped: begin
      if mediaplayer1.Error = 0 then begin
        mediaplayer1.Notify := true;
        mediaplayer1.Wait := false;
        mediaplayer1.Play;
      end;
    end;
  end;
end;
```

Answer (score 5):

The `TMediaPlayer` is a *control*, so you should naturally not use it unless you want precisely its GUI.

If you only want to play a audio file repeatedly, use the [`PlaySound`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd743680%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function in `MMSystem.pas`:

```
PlaySound('test.wav', 0, SND_FILENAME or SND_NODEFAULT or SND_ASYNC or SND_LOOP)
```